# Is there a management API for Standard Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

There is a Logic Apps management API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows)

As far as I understood you cannot use the service to access Standard Logic Apps. Is there a work around? Basically I need to retrieve a few days of action outputs of my running workflow.  TIA

Comment: you could have a look at this link. Ig you have app-insights / log-analytics enabled, you should be able to query through azure monitor queries: https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/monitoring-logic-apps-standard-with-app-insights-querying

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I need to retrieve a few days of action outputs of my running workflow.

Like mentioned by @Thomas, One of the workarounds is to enable application insights from your logic apps and then retrieve the action outputs of your workflow in log analytics using KQL.

[image]

In Application Insights, I'm using the below query to get the information about each and every action where its state is in **Running**.

```
traces 
| where cloud_RoleName == "<Your_LogicApp_Name>"
| where message contains "Running"
| where operation_Name  != ""
```

[image]